# Patterns in makefile targets

Tags: makefile

Makefile:

```
%_file:
     touch $@

foo_%: %_file

bar: foo_bar
```

Results:

```
>make foo_bar
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo_bar'.  Stop.

>make bar
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo_bar', needed by 'bar'.  Stop.
```

I have intentionally omitted adding `.PHONY` rules because I know the prerequisites of phony rules are always interpreted as literals. I do not see any reason that `make foo_bar` or `make bar` should not run without error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify @larsks answer, the [GNU make manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html):

> You can cancel a built-in implicit rule by defining a pattern rule with the same target and prerequisites, but no recipe.

So your pattern rule:

```
foo_%: %_file
```

does not *create* a pattern rule, it *deletes* a (non-existent anyway) pattern rule.

If you want a pattern rule it *must* have a recipe.

Comment: Hmm. I see that's what's happening, but `foo_%` *isn't* "a built-in implicit rule." Irritating that this behavior applies here.

Comment: Regardless of whether the pattern rule is built in or not, if you don't have a recipe it's not defining a pattern rule.  The term "built-in" is used in the manual because of context but actually it applies to any pattern rule.  That's how you get rid if a pattern rule you don't want regardless of how it was created.

Comment: Put another way: it's not possible to define a pattern rule that doesn't have a recipe.  That simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have a dependency between `foo_%` and `%_file`, but you have defined any rules on how to build `foo_%`. So when you run:

```
make foo_bar
```

Make figures out it first needs to build `bar_file`, but can't find any rules for building `foo_bar`. If you were to write instead:

```
%_file:
    touch $@

foo_%: %_file
    cp $< $@

bar: foo_bar
```

Then running `make foo_bar` would result in:

```
touch bar_file
cp bar_file foo_bar
rm bar_file
```